# Как сделать так, чтобы при переделывании шапки на компоненты в PHP класс active перебрасывался?

Tags: php, html, css

У меня в верстке есть шапка. Там есть 4 страницы: "Главная", "Магазин", "О бренде", "Контакты". Сейчас на этапе PHP, делаю так, чтобы все повторяющиеся моменты были подключены через отдельный файл. Например в  у меня есть линки, я их подключил через отдельный файл с помощью `<?php require_once 'includes/components/head_links.php'?>`. А теперь нужно точно так же сделать с шапкой с перебросом класса "active". Заранее благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

И в чем же проблема?

```php
$cssClass = 'active';
require_once 'includes/components/header.php';
```

> header.php

```php
echo "<div class=\"".$cssClass."\"> ... </div>\n";
```